# Sending email through Cygwin

Tags: linux, shell, cygwin, sh, email-client

I have a written a shell script wherein I want to send an email through it. I am executing this script on windows through cygwin. I have installed **email** package on my machine. However, I am having a hard time making it work. Please let me know what is the easiest way to send email through cygwin command prompt.

My ssmtp.conf file is :

```
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
FromLineOverride=YES
rewriteDomain=gmail.com
root=aci.lfindba@gmail.com
UseTLS=YES
AuthUser=userid
AuthPass=password
```

and email.conf file has:

```
SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT = '25'
MY_NAME  = 'ABC'
MY_EMAIL = 'emailaddress'
REPLY_TO = 'emailaddress'
USE_TLS = 'true'
ADDRESS_BOOK = '&/email.address.template'
SMTP_AUTH = 'LOGIN'
SMTP_AUTH_USER = 'userid'
SMTP_AUTH_PASS = 'password'
```

I am using below command to send email:
echo "mail body"|email -s "subject" recipient@gmail.com
However, I am getting following error:
**email: FATAL: Could not connect to server: smtp.gmail.com on port: 25: Operation not permitted**

Please help.

Comment: Does `nc smtp.gmail.com 25` work? If not then you have a firewall problem.

Comment: If cygwin doesn't have `nc` then `telnet smtp.gmail.com 25` does the same thing.

Comment: neither nc nor telnet woked on machine...I didn't even find package for them in cygwin.

Comment: `telnet` can be found in the `inetutils` package, and `nc` can be found in the confusingly named `nc` package. http://cygwin.com/packages/

Answer (score 1):

I use the `msmtp` package, with this configuration:

```
port 587
auth on
from srpen6@gmail.com
host smtp.gmail.com
tls on
tls_certcheck off
user srpen6@gmail.com
```

https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=msmtp&arch=x86_64

Comment: I found msmtp to be the simplest solution, much easier to configure than ssmtp.  I am using it with Cygwin on Windows 10 to allow automated messages to be passed to the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

Install and configure the `ssmtp` package.

Create `/bin/mail` with these contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# copyright 2016 Gene Pavlovsky [http://www.razorscript.com]
#
# mail: mail-like wrapper script for sendmail

SENDMAIL=/usr/sbin/ssmtp

usage()
{
  {
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0) [-s "subject"] [-f from-addr] [to-addr]..."
    echo
    echo "Sends mail."
    echo
    echo "Options:"
    echo -e "  -s\tsubject (quote subjects containing spaces)"
    echo -e "  -f\tfrom address"
  } >&2
  exit 2
}

while test $# -gt 0; do
  case $1 in
    -s)
            shift
            test $# -eq 0 && usage
            subj=$1
    ;;
    -f)
            shift
            test $# -eq 0 && usage
            from=$1
    ;;
    -*)
      usage
    ;;
    *)
            rcpt+=( "$1" )
    ;;
  esac

  shift
  test "$end_options" = yes && break
done

test ${#rcpt} -eq 0 && usage

{
    test "$from" && echo From: $from
    test "$subj" && echo Subject: $subj
    echo
    exec /bin/cat
} | "$SENDMAIL" "${rcpt[@]}"
```

Don't forget to `chmod 755 /bin/mail`.